# Calculating the Taylor Polynomial of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How do I compute the third Taylor polynomial of the following piecewise function at $0$?

Given that

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}, &x\neq 0 \\ 1 & x=0 \end{cases}$$

EDITED: I am wondering whether I have to compute the Taylor polynomial for each component of the piecewise function, or I simply do it just for $\displaystyle\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$? If we apply it for each component, isn't it the case that evaluating the Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $0$ always give $1$?

Answer (score 3):

Start with the Taylor series for $\sin(t)$, substitute $x^2$ for $t$, and divide each term by $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to get the Taylor series expansion for $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$ but do I do anything with the $1$ since i'm taking the Taylor expansion for $f$ and if this is so, wouldn't the Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $0$ always just give $1$?

Comment: The $1$ is just there to make the value at $0$ equal to the limit as $x \to 0$ (i.e. to remove the removable singularity).  The series does that automatically.

Comment: So am I correct about the Taylor Polynomial of $f(x)$ at x_0 =0  simply being $T_n(x) = 1$?

Comment: $T_3(x) = 1$, but $T_4(x) = 1 - x^4/6$.